# How to boot centos for recovery without monitor or DVD?

Tags: boot, centos, fstab

I modified the fstab to include the newly created partition, then rebooted. But the system won't boot, and I suspect it is due to incorrect information in fstab.

My machine has no monitor, no working DVD, and only accessible using keyboard, and LAN/WLAN.

How can I fix this issue? Is there any keyboard input during boot to send the OS to rescue mode? Or any way to enable network access to modify the fstab?

Answer (score 0):

Unless the system has some sought of remote management interface like HP's iLO or Dell's DRAC then no, as you have to edit the boot arguments for GRUB to enter Rescue Mode. You need some way to see the console to edit the GRUB config on start-up.

If you do get the system back up, I always mount my external drives for backup like this in the fstab file:

```
    /dev/sde /ext_hdd defaults 0 0
```

And it works every time without fail for me (replace the "/dev/sde" for your own configuration).

Answer (score 0):

1. if you have another physical machine. Put this physical hard drive in that machine
2. Install vmware or virtual box and use this physical hard drive as the disk
3. Boot he virtual machine
4. you should be able to see the console and work from there

Please let me know if you require any clarification